# How to filter Pandas rows based on last/next row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two data sets from different pulse oximeters, and plot them with pyplot as displayed below. As you may see, the green data sheet has alot of outliers(vertical drops). In my work I've defined these outlayers as non-valid in for my statistical analysis, they are must certainly not measurements. Therefore I argue that I can simply remove them.

The characteristics of these rogue values is that they're single(or top two) value outliers(see df below). The "real" sample values are either the same as the previous value, or +-1. In e.g. java(pseudo code) I would do something like:

```
for(i; i <df.length; i++)
  if (df[i+1|-1].spo2 - df[i].spo2 > 1|-1)
    df[i].drop
```

What would be the pandas(numpy?) equivalent of what I'm trying to do, remove values that is more/less than 1 compared to the last/next value?

---

df:

```
    time, spo2
1900-01-01 18:18:41.194  98.0
1900-01-01 18:18:41.376  98.0
1900-01-01 18:18:41.559  78.0
1900-01-01 18:18:41.741  98.0
1900-01-01 18:18:41.923  98.0
1900-01-01 18:18:42.105  90.0
1900-01-01 18:18:42.288  97.0
1900-01-01 18:18:42.470  97.0
1900-01-01 18:18:42.652  98.0
```

[image: sensor data from two pulse oximeters]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at [pandas.DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). This is a column-wise operation that shifts all rows in a given column to another row of another column:

```
# original df

   x1                 
0   0
1   1 
2   2
3   3
4   4 

# shift down
df.x2 = df.x1.shift(1) 

   x1  x2
0   0   NaN  # Beware
1   1   0
2   2   1
3   3   2
4   4   3

# Shift up
df.x2 = df.x1.shift(-1)

   x1  x2
0   0   1
1   1   2
2   2   3
3   3   4
4   4   NaN  # Beware
```

You can use this to move `spo2` of timestamp `n+1` next to `spo2` in the timestamp `n` row. Then, filter based on conditions applied to that one row.

```
df['spo2_Next'] = df['spo2'].shift(-1)
# replace NaN to allow float comparison
df.spo2_Next.fillna(1, inplace = True)
# Apply your row-wise condition to create filter column
df.loc[((df.spo2_Next - df.spo2) > 1) or ((df.spo2_Next - df.spo2) < 1), 'Outlier'] = True
# filter
df_clean = df[df.Outlier != True]
# remove filter column
del df_clean['Outlier']
```

Answer (score 1):

When you filter a pandas dataframe like:

df[ df.colum1 = 2 & df.colum2 < 3 ], you are:

- comparing a numeric series to a scalar value and generating a boolean series
- obtaining two boolean series and doing a logical and
- then using a numeric series to filter the data frame (the false values will not be added in the new data frame)

So you just need create an iterative algorithm over the data frame to produce such boolean array, and use it to filter the dataframe, as in:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])

df[ [True, False, True]]
```

You can also create a closure to filter the data frame (using df.apply), and keeping previous observations in the closure to detect abrupt changes, but this would be way too complicated. I would go for the straightforward imperative solution.